# why the clion did not have entry cmake project from source

Tags: clion

why the CLion `CLion 2021.3.4` did not have the entry of `New CMake project from source`?

[image]

how to import the CMake projects from CLion?

Comment: Just open the project, it will open the "Project wizard" window, then it will proceed to import the CMake project.

Comment: I already tried this, no CMake project tips.@Nicolas